# What do the tower settings mean?

Tags: spice-bandits

I'm having a bit of trouble when placing the towers- do the `f`, `s`, `w` tower settings actually mean anything?

Answer (score 4):

It means which enemy will tower shoot first, Fastest, Slowest, Weakest.

Answer (score 2):

As Davor says, the letters identify which enemy to attack, but I think they mean the following:

F = First

S = Strongest

W = Weakest